# Filter email view in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

From MS Outlook I am used to have an input field above my list of mails where I can type in a filter string such that every mail not matching this string vanishes. I remember that once - by accident (pressing a weird combination of keys because the window I was actually working in lost focus) - I got something very similar in Lotus Notes. So I think there must be something like this out there, but unfortunately I cannot find it anymore.

Does somebody know how to get this kind of functionality in Lotus Notes? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try View - Search This View. This adds a search bar on the top of the folder/view where you can search (filter) the mail below.

Comment: That's it! And it's so simple - how could I miss it?